# Expected value of a probability greater than a constant value

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a score function $\xi$ based on Jaccard similarity like this:

$\xi(A, B) = \frac{M_{11}}{M_{11} + {M_{10}} + M_{01}}$

where $A, B \in \{0,1\}^N$, and $M_{xy}$ is the number of elements with value $x \in \{0,1\}$ in $A$ and value $y \in \{0,1\}$ in $B$.

Considered that I obtain $B$ with random perturbations of the elements of $A$ with perturbation probability $p$, i.e., (independently for each element) with probability  I invert the element of  (e.g., from 0 to 1, or from 1 to 0), I would say that the expected score is:

$\mathbb{E}[\xi] = \frac{ N_1(1-p)}{N_1(1-p) + Np}$,

where $N_1$ is the number of elements equal to 1 in $A$.

1. Is this correct?

Moreover, if I independently repeat this perturbation over $A$, I obtain different vectors $B_1, B_2, ..., B_n$. Then, I would like to define a value $n_{t^*}$ that represents the fraction of perturbed vectors whose score with $A$ is over a certain threshold $t^*$, i.e., (I suppose) $Pr[\xi(A, B_i) > t^*]$.

2. Is it correct (is it formal) to say that $\mathbb{E}(n_{t^*}) = Pr[\xi(A, B_i) > t^*]$?
3. How to compute the expected value $\mathbb{E}(n_{t^*})$?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: With probability $p$ I invert the element of $A$ (e.g., from 0 to 1, or from 1 to 0).

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I use the word "perturbation". Sorry for that, I will edit the question above :-)

Comment: 1. cannot be correct as it should depend on the structure of $A$. If there are $n$ of 1's in $A$ then your score will be $\frac{n(1-p)}{n(1-p)+Np}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you... I noticed that after I posed the question... however, I'm still not sure that the expected value of that ratio is the ratio of the expected values

Comment: However, I fixed the question

Comment: You just copied the expression, but did not explain in the question the meaning of $n$ . Besides there can be a confusion because later you use the symbol $n$ in another context.

Comment: Should be ok now